# Visual Studio .NET Ref-Def-Mismatch on pre-build event

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-assembly, buildconfiguration

I have a pre-build event in my C# project set to the following:

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
"$(DevEnvDir)devenv.exe"  "$(SolutionDir)..\MyApp\MyApp.sln" /build $(Configuration)
REM ****** Copy some dependencies ******
ECHO Copy unmanged dlls
COPY  $(SolutionDir)..\MyApp\x64\$(Configuration)\MyApp.dll $(TargetDir)\.
COPY  $(SolutionDir)..\MyApp\x64\$(Configuration)\MyApp.pdb $(TargetDir)\.
COPY  $(SolutionDir)..\MyApp\x64\$(Configuration)\MyAppInterop.dll $(TargetDir)\.
COPY $(SolutionDir)..\MyApp\x64\$(Configuration)\MyAppInterop.pdb $(TargetDir)\.
REM ******COPY complete ******
```

which compiles a solution and copies MyApp.dll and MyAppInterop.dll to my target directory so that my C# project uses the c++ CLI interop MyAppInterop.dll to reference its assembly. However, when the build of MyAppInterop succeeds, it is assigned a new version. The current reference in my C# references the previous build version. Is there a way to tell the IDE/Compiler to use this newly copied version instead of the old one during the pre-build stage...? I can see that the file is correctly copied into the destination which I expect it to be. Also, in VS I see the following in the output:

> Considered "....\x64\Debug\MyAppInterop.dll", but its name "MyAppInterop, Version=1.0.4980.14942, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddf0b8c12962ac51" didn't match.

It found the dll it, just didn't like the version number. I'm hoping it's just as easy as running a "replace" assembly command for the current build. Is this possible ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using strongly named assemblies? If so would it be an option to not do so?

Comment: I found something like "sn -Ra $(TargetPath) $(ProjectDir)FullKey.snk" on my post-build event for my C++/CLI app. I modified it to sn $(TargetPath) $(ProjectDir)FullKey.snk -Pb n according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23.aspx . Still won't build on my C# project. Is there another setting I need to consider :)?

Comment: Clearly the feature that gets msbuild to auto-generate a version number is one that you don't like right now.  So use my doctor's typical advice, if it hurts then don't do it.

Comment: @Hans - Yes, that is very clear to me, hence me posting this question on stackoverflow to make the "hurting" go away :) The fix is simply to re-add the reference before building by manually removing and then re-adding (since the old dll is over-ridden). I'm looking for an automatic method for this...

Comment: The entire approach is mysterious.  VS readily supports building multiple projects in one solution, nothing special about a C++/CLI project.  So there's just no obvious need to hack something with a prebuild event.  Just add the project to the solution and add the reference to the C++/CLI project as a project dependency.  Problem solved.

Comment: @Hans did you mean I had the wrong switch for "-Pb n"? I changed it to yes instead but still no-go...

Comment: Yes, I would agree with putting all the projects in one solution but the idea was to  keep them separate for "developer friendliness" . This is turning out a lot more complicated than I hoped for so I may be calling it quits.. The "Specific Version" attribute for the assembly (listed under assembly properties) is always on for the dll I build(even with -Pb y). I could manually turn it to false but then when I gets copied over during pre-build, it returns to true.